# How to access linked documents using Dql?

Tags: database, document, dql, document-database

I need to check a field in a document and a field in other document that is being referred by the first one. Can I do it with DQL?

Here is my code and my wish between quotes.

```
public function findByCode($code, $email)
{
        return $this->createQueryBuilder()

            ->field('code')->equals($code)
            ->field("""""user->email""""")->equals($email)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult()
            ;

}
```